# C# range.Rows.Count doesn't count right - Excel formating?

Tags: c#, excel, count, range

I'm using C# to get data from Excel.

For reading out the Data I use this piece of code:

`for (int rCnt = 2; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)`

The Sheet is 80 rows long, the `range.Rows.Count` says it is 135 rows long.
I have this problem with 2 Excel Files. 
The Excel files are generated from an Sharepoint and have filters and some other formating.
When I copy the data into an empty Excel file (with Strg + A, not manually selected) it counts the right amount of rows.
With a 3rd Excel file (from an Sharepoint, too) its no problem...

Maybe a solution is to change the excel file first, it is only needed for my programm not for anything else, so that would be ok.

Any Ideas?

Edit:

I just stopped the code and saw, that after the range of 80, all the entries in the object are "null", so there is no hidden Data or something

Edit2: 
I deleted all the Data from that Sheet and now it counts 137 rows, so there has to be some formating stuff that is counted...

Comment: the problem might be that you are calling the .Rows.Count on a `range` object I suppose. A range can be like `Range("A1:A135")` and misleading you a bit....Does it make a difference if you call it on the `activeSheet.Rows.Count`?

Comment: When I Use the `activeSheet.Rows.Count` I'ts Count = 1048576

Comment: Can you confirm that there really are 80 rows in the sheet? no hidden rows etc?

Comment: Yes, I now did a check, if the value is "null", it doesn't calculate further. 
It was some formating in the sheet, it was fillet with blanks from A1 - A135, I don't know why!The solution works for me (it counts until 135 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you mention that the excel file has some filtering and formatting. Could it be that some of the formatting is applied to the first 135 rows in the file and therefore the select returns them all ?
And secondly, what do you use to read the Excel file ? Do you use OleDb? 
And are the rest of the returned rows empty ?

If that is the case you can use : SELECT * FROM SHEET WHERE [Column] IS NOT NULL

Comment: There has to be some Formating in the File, I now deleted all the Data from that Sheet and it counts 137 (2 more than before ?!)

Comment: I agree, and I would guess that the same happens when you are printing the Excel sheet. But doesn't selecting only the rows that have some content by using the Where clause help ?